# The Sims 4 Deluxe Party upgrade (PS4)

Tags: ps4, psn, the-sims-4

I bought the Deluxe Party Edition upgrade for The Sims 4 on PS4.

If I go to the PS store to download it, it shows a download button but when I press it, it refreshes the screen and it doesn't start downloading.

When I try to download it from a browser it doesn't show the download button, instead it just says purchased.

How can I access this content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sims 4, the content is already in the game, by buying the upgrades/expacs/etc you essentially "unlock" the content.

I'd advise you to **first check the Notifications section** to see if anything was actually downloaded and then simply **boot up the game** and see if the content advertised by this upgrade is actually available to plop down.

Comment: In The Sims 4 you have a screen where you can see all the packages you have bought, this upgrade is not visible as purchased.

Comment: I'm talking about [main menu](https://simsvip.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/32634371976_182cb26669_o.png)